# Add an already running server to kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kops

large server running with my apps.  And I have being trying to improve the way my apps are being deployed and my pipeline. Right now I have no kubernetes running I did some tests with kops and eks, but right now I cannot afford the extra cost with EKS.  I want to run kubernetes master node on an free tier t2.micro, and because I already paid for m3 server upfront I would like to migrate all my apps to use kubernetes and for the moment run on my m3.large server and If i need more nodes in the future I could just lunch them.
I am not sure on how to add my server to the cluster. Or if I can do this.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to run kubernetes on only a single master node and if it is on a t2.micro you should really stay away from using kubernetes like this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Kops uses autoscaling groups under the hood, as do most AWS deployments. Look at kubespray instead perhaps.